# NativeScript Firebase Google Authentication

Tags: android, nativescript

I am using NativeScript (Vue app) with the Firebase plugin to allow Google account logins.
The login button redirects to Google sign-in page but I cannot sign in.  The error displayed is "This account already exists on your phone."

According to the [plugin page](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/AUTHENTICATION.md) this will happen if the SHA1 fingerprints have not been uploaded to the Firebase console.

There is no difference between a physical device or the emulator, neither between "tns run" and "tns build" and then uploading the APK manually.

The command I use is

```
tns run android --key-store-path ./keyStore.jks --key-store-password <my_keystore_password> --key-store-alias <my_alias> --key-store-alias-password <my_alias_password> --bundle
```

I followed these steps:

1. Used keytool to get the SHA1 and added it to the Firebase
   console.
2. Downloaded the google-services.json file and added
   it to the app/App_Resources/Android folder.
3. Used apksigner to
       verify the SHA1 and it matches what I have in the Firebase console
       as well as the keystore.

When I check the Firebase Analytics page I can see the connection, so I am using the correct app URI etc.

The following is printed in the terminal window:

```
JS: 'Make sure you\'ve uploaded your SHA1 fingerprint(s) to the Firebase console. Status: Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12502, resolution=null}'
JS: 'Has the SHA1 fingerprint been uploaded? Sign-in status: Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12502, resolution=null}'
```

I noticed another question regarding this on SO but it's not been answered and is a few years old.

Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try a clean build after replacing your `google-services.json` in your `App_Resources/Android` directory?

Comment: I did yes, using the --clean parameter.

Comment: can u please tell me how to generate sha-1 for my nativescript app?

Comment: @RobertWilliams https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

Answer (score 0):

Something that worked for me was to delete the "Platforms" directory from the project files and then run `tns build android --bundle`.

I would also just verify that your SHA1 fingerprint that you can find with:
`keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore`
is the same as one listed in your Firebase settings. (https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)

The other thing to check would be that you downloaded the google-services.json file after you added the SHA1 fingerprint.  But it seems like you've already done most of that.

Answer (score 0):

- You have to provide yet another SHA-1 fingerprint.
- Locate your debug.keystore (usually in %USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore).
- Use keytool to retrieve key information as you did with your upload keystore.
- Put retrieved SHA-1 into firebase authentication console.

That's all folks.

Comment: That didn't work for me. I deleted the project and started a new one which worked.